# DataContractSerializer and Generic lists

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer, xml-deserialization

I have problem deserializing a list from my xml file. My properties are internal, so I am using datacontractserializer not xmlserializer.

My xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Root">
    <BackgroundColor>
        0,0,255
    </BackgroundColor>
    <RowGap>1</RowGap>
    <Table>
        <TableHeading>"H1"</TableHeading>
        <StartingColumn>A</StartingColumn>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <TableHeading>"H2"</TableHeading>
        <StartingColumn>B</StartingColumn>
    </Table>    
</Root>
```

Root has List of Table. The ListOfTables is not being deserialized.
Classes are

```
[DataContract()]
public class Root
{
    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnSerializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (Table == null)
        {
            Table = new List<TableStructure>();
        }
     }

     [DataMember(Name = "RowGap")]
     internal int RowGap { get; set; }

     [DataMember(Name = "TableHeaderBackgroundColor")]
     internal string HdrBackColor  { get; set; }

     [DataMember()]
     internal List<TableStructure> Table { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "Table", Namespace = "")]
public sealed class TableStructure 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string TableHeading { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string StartingColumn { get; set; }
}
```

The desrialize method

```
internal static Root GetSettings()
{
     Root settings;
     using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Root.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
     {
          using (XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fs, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()))
          {
              var x = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Root));
              settings = (Root)x.ReadObject(reader);
              reader.Close();
              fs.Close();
          }
     }
     return settings;
}
```

This executes without any error, but do not load any table info. RowGap and color is being loaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your solution to get it work (added XML namespaces too):

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Root")]
public class Root
{
    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnSerializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (Table == null)
        {
            Table = new List<TableStructure>();
        }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "RowGap")]
    internal int RowGap { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "TableHeaderBackgroundColor")]
    internal string HdrBackColor { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Tables")]
    internal List<TableStructure> Table { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "Table", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Root")]
public sealed class TableStructure
{
    [DataMember(Name = "StartingColumn")]
    public string TableHeading { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "TableHeading")]
    public string StartingColumn { get; set; }
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Root">
  <BackgroundColor>
    0,0,255
  </BackgroundColor>
  <RowGap>1</RowGap>
  <!-- Used as container element for list -->
  <Tables>
    <Table>
      <!-- Sorted elements alphabetically -->
      <StartingColumn>A</StartingColumn>
      <TableHeading>"H1"</TableHeading>
    </Table>
    <Table>
      <!-- Sorted elements alphabetically -->
      <StartingColumn>B</StartingColumn>
      <TableHeading>"H2"</TableHeading>
    </Table>
  </Tables>
</Root>
```

**Note:** The order of the XML elements is taken into account by the `DataContractSerializer` as mentioned here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a891928b-d27a-4ef2-83b3-ee407c6b9187/order-of-data-members-in-the-xml-string-influences-deserialization-datacontractserializer?forum=wcf. As you did not sort the elements alphabetically I modified the XML file to meet the behavior of the `DataContractSerializer`.

You can specify the order of the XML elements using the [DataMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute and its [DataMember.Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.order%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

How did you create the xml? By hand or through a serializer?
There should be an extra `<Table>` element (representing the `Root.Table` property) surrounding the existing `<Table>` elements (representing each `TableStructure` instance).

This xml (created by `DataContractSerializer`) deserializes as expected on my machine:

```
<Root xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestDataGrid" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RowGap>101</RowGap>
    <Table>
        <Table xmlns="">
            <StartingColumn>1</StartingColumn>
            <TableHeading>First</TableHeading>
        </Table>
        <Table xmlns="">
            <StartingColumn>2</StartingColumn>
            <TableHeading>Second</TableHeading>
        </Table>
    </Table>
    <TableHeaderBackgroundColor>c0ffee</TableHeaderBackgroundColor>
</Root>
```

Comment: the original Table element does not have xmlns attribute, what happen when you remove the attribute and deserialize it?

Comment: If you remove the empty `xmlns` attributes from the xml I posted, the `Table`s won't deserialize. They are somehow needed to tell the deserializer that the class resides in a different namespace than `Root`. If you mark the `Root` class with the _same_ namespace however (`[DataContract(Namespace = "")]`), you don't get those xmlns attributes in the xml anymore.

Comment: then you should mention your changes in the answer

Comment: Well, it's why I asked where the original xml came from. It doesn't look like it was made through `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: Yes, it was created by hand. But I tried with an extra tag earlier, it was not working. I have fixed it now by correcting the namespace. Thanks